# pyclewn with cross GDB

Tags: vim, gdb

I'm looking to use pyclewn with with a cross compiled version of GDB. So far I have not had much luck figuring out how to specify which GDB to use (in my case /home/ARM/DevTools/bin/arm-none-eabi-gdb).

I can run pyclewn from VIM, but it starts the local linux gdb.

I am also hoping to connect gdb to an OpenOCD server (within VIM/Pyclewn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start vim and set the `pyclewn_args` global variable *before* running `:Pyclewn`, for example:

```
:let g:pyclewn_args = "--pgm=/home/ARM/DevTools/bin/arm-none-eabi-gdb"
```

There seems to be a bug somewhere in that if you run `:Pyclewn` and then issue the `let` command, the new value of `pyclewn_args` seem to be ignored by the next invocations of `:Pyclewn`.